# Custom post type archive root level theming

Tags: wordpress

I'm stuck with a theming question. I have a Custom Post Type (Products) and a Custom Taxonomy (Product Types).

The CPT Archive checks if there are any direct Taxonomy children and if yes, displays them. If not, shows the products. So far, so good. Works fine. (Like a very basic shop system but without any plugin.)

But now I need to change layout of *only* the root level of the CPT Archive, where there are only child taxonomies visible. This must not affect any other level.

I have no real idea how to go for this.

Which are the filters I am searching for ("if this is the root level of the archive, show....")?

Answer (score 0):

Please create a file in your theme folder with the name **archive-custom-post-type.php**, like if **chef** is a custom post type **archive-chef.php** will be the archive page.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody ever wonders the same, the solution was quite easy actually ;-)

I decided to read out the current wordpress URL for the archive and some research later I found the perfect solution here:
https://roots.io/routing-wp-requests/

Add this function to the functions.php:

```
function get_current_url() {
    // Get current URL path, stripping out slashes on boundaries
    $current_url = trim(esc_url_raw(add_query_arg([])), '/');
    // Get the path of the home URL, stripping out slashes on boundaries
    $home_path = trim(parse_url(home_url(), PHP_URL_PATH), '/');
    // If a URL part exists, and the current URL part starts with it...
    if ($home_path && strpos($current_url, $home_path) === 0) {
        // ... just remove the home URL path form the current URL path
        $current_url = trim(substr($current_url, strlen($home_path)), '/');
    }

    return $current_url;
}
```

in the archive-cpt.php, a simple if else statement did the job.